# Redirecting joined calls

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to join 2 calls, then redirect those calls to another TwiML URL.

First call I initiate with

```
$call = $client->calls->create(
           "+11111111111", "+13035551212", array("url" => "twiml.start.php")
        );
```

twiml.start.php then has:

```
<Response>
<Dial>2222222222</Dial>
```

I can hear both calls at that point. Then I try to redirect it:

```
$client
        ->calls($call->sid) //SID from the first call
        ->update(
        array(
            "url" => "twiml.new.php",
            "method" => "POST"
        )
    );
```

At this point, the call to 1111111111 gets the twiml.new.php file, but the call to 2222222222 gets disconnected. How can I redirect the joined call to the new destination without disconnecting it?

Answer (score 1):

Take the original two calls and join them in a conference.

Then, dial out and serve a TwiML that will join the third caller with the other 2.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request#code-make-call-using-twilio

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your second caller is getting disconnected because you are only redirecting one leg of the call, the first caller. The second caller is then left on the line to no-one so the call hangs up.

It would be better, as austinhollis suggests, to [dial the two callers into a conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference). This means that even as one call is redirected away the other call won't be dropped.

If you need to [redirect both calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) then you will need to make two API calls using the individual Call SIDs of each call (you will get the call SIDs when the callers connect to the initial TwiML).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, what's an "evangelist" in terms of a developer? (I actually don't know, but I see it everywhere, sorry for derailing)

Comment: No problem! I am a developer, but it is my job to reach out to developers to make them aware of the Twilio platform and help them with it if possible. Some of the things I do include answering questions on SO, speaking at conferences/meetups, writing blog posts, writing example applications, learning new technologies and mentoring at hackathons. Hope that helps :)